# Table valued function in SQL Server; the table in the function is temporary?

Tags: sql-server

For the table valued functions in SQL Server, when one executes something like the following, it only creates the temporary table `@Table`, just like with the variables (in scalar-valued functions), correct? Would any issues arise if many such statements were to be executed?

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_function
     (@some_var varchar(20), @someDate date)
RETURNS @Table Table (id int, name varchar(50), DoB date)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Table
        SELECT id, Name, CAST(DoB as date) 
        FROM tblEmployees

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: This isn't a temporary table, it's just a variable. In this example though, you don't even need it. You could create an inline function and return the results directly. This would allow the optimizer to create a better plan *and* save copying the data into the variable first before returning it

Comment: Please read this answer on DBA.SE...http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: Look at here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/naga/2015/05/10/sql-server-performance-tuning-table-variable-vs-temporary-tables/

Comment: The terminology you're looking for is that this is a Table Variable rather than a Temp Table

Comment: this table is just to make my point clear. I have taken it from youTube. Got it. So no tables are created. Just the table variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would any issues arise if many such statements were to be executed?

No, that is [not possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx):

> The scope of a local variable is the batch in which it is declared.

Table variable's scope is same as scalar variable's.

[About table variable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02337dd5-5cfd-40d8-b529-12dc557d6a7e/scope-of-table-variable-and-temp-table?forum=sqltools) and temp table, briefly:

> The scope of a table variable is limited to the specific batch, while a local temporary table is limited to the specific spid.

Which means even if you are running same code from several threads - they will not conflict on `#` table names, since each thread will have own `spid`. Different users (different connections) cannot conflict nor on table variable names (not possible at all) neither on temp table names (not possible against different connections).

Only conflicts on `##` (global temp tables) and `#` within same connection (e.g. nested procedures trying to create temp table with same name) are possible.